# Using the unzip command in SSH with Mac Terminal not working

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, unzip

I logging into my server from the Mac Terminal Bash Shell and the unzip command is not working I keep getting the following message:

```
bash: unzip: command not found
```

Can I unzip a file via SSH from Mac Terminal?

Comment: I'm a little rusty with Mac file structure, but check /bin for the unzip program itself.

Comment: Furthermore, there might also by a gzip and gunzip, if you have the correct version of Macintosh. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/gzip.1.html . If you can tell us what version of Mac OS you're using, it can help a lot.

Comment: FYI, `unzip` lives in `/usr/bin/` on OS X 10.8.2

Also, are you running `unzip` on the Mac, or on the remote machine? If it's on the remote machine, which kind of machine is it (if it's not a Mac).

Comment: I am rnning unzip on CentOS 5. The command works when I use it on windows with pUTTY

Comment: @MojaRa I'm confused, are you running UNZip on the Mac server, or the CentOS 5 server ?

Comment: I am running the unzip command in the Bash shell on the CentOS server. But I am loging in from my Mac using the Terminal. When I login I am in a Bash shell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The program `unzip` should be in `/usr/bin`:

```
$ type unzip
unzip is /usr/bin/unzip
```

Worst case, you can always just "ask for it by name":

```
$ /usr/bin/unzip foo.zip
```

You should check your `PATH` variable, as it should normally include `/usr/bin`:

```
$ echo $PATH
$ PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH
$ export PATH
```

Make sure you have selected a **login shell** for your Terminal. This will set a good value for the `PATH` variable when the shell starts.

Comment: Unzip is installed but when I login to my remote site via ssh the command does not work.

Comment: I just tested the unzip command on my mac in terminal and it works it just does not work when I log in via SSH

Comment: Are you trying to run `unzip` on the **OS X** box or the **CentOS** box? The **OS X** box should have it, the **CentOS** may not. If you are an admin of the **CentOS** box, you can `yum install unzip`, if it's missing.

Comment: I am the admin on the CentOS box. I tried yum and wget and neither worked to install unzip

Comment: So on the **CentOS** box, `$ ls /usr/bin/unzip` returns an error and `$ sudo yum install unzip` also returns an error? If so, can you tell me what the error is? You could also try `$ sudo yum install unzip.x86_64` assuming you are on a 64-bit box, but I believe this is unnecessary.

Comment: when I try to use the su or sudo command I get a message of 
 sudo: command not found
or
 su: command not found

Comment: ok, you essentially have no `PATH`. You can run a new **login shell** on top of your existing shell: `$ /bin/bash -l`. Now you should be able to either run `unzip` or at least `/bin/su` or `/usr/bin/sudo`.

Comment: How do I run a new login shell on top of my existing. I need some guidance on what commands I need to use?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22078/discussion-between-jeberle-and-moja-ra)

Comment: You were right I went into my server and change the type a shell there and now unzip works.